# Not getting cookie in Django

Tags: python, json, django, cookies

pretty new to Django and I am having a hard time solving a situation on a project that I am working on.

I am setting my cookies via JS as JSON and trying to request them in the backend.

My code for the JS is:

```
function getCookie(name) {
        // Split cookie string and get all individual name=value pairs in an array
        var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");

        // Loop through the array elements
        for(var i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
        var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");

        /* Removing whitespace at the beginning of the cookie name and compare it with the given string */
        if(name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
          // Decode the cookie value and return
          return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
        }
    }

    // Return null if not found
    return null;
}

var cart = JSON.parse(getCookie('cart'))

if (cart == undefined){
    cart = {}
    console.log('Cart Created!', cart)
    document.cookie ='cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"
}
console.log('Cart:', cart)
```

[The cookie is made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgBtc.png)

After that I try to get to cart cookie in the backend.
Also the items added to the cart are displayed in the console.

[Console info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXWfO.png)

My backend code is:

```
def cart(request):
    print(request.COOKIES)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer,
            complete=False,
            )
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cart_items = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        try:
            bag = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
            print('CART ITEMS:', bag)
        except KeyError:
            bag = {}
            print('CART ITEMS:', bag)

        items = []
        order = {
            'get_cart_total': 0,
            'get_cart_items': 0,
            }
        cart_items = order['get_cart_items']

        for i in bag:
            cart_items += bag[i]['quantity']

    context = {
        'items': items,
        'order': order,
        'cart_items': cart_items,
        }

    return render(request, 'cart/cart.html', context)
```

[Image from the terminal with the data that it retrieves from the cookie:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sqX4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not setting cookies properly (like expire time is missing), [please check this out](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Also, to keep things simple instead of using try/except you can just use `bag = json.loads(request.COOKIES.get('cart',{})`

**Update:**

Instead of max-age use this -

```
const d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
let expires = d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = `cart=${cart};expires=${expires}; path=/`;
```

Comment: I've tried setting a max-age on my variable:

`document.cookie ='cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + "; max-age=3600; domain=; path=/"`

But it does not do the trick

Comment: @GeorgeF use expires instead of max-age, i have updated the answer